# setAttribute function on checkbox not affecting target button

Tags: javascript, checkbox, disable

I know this question has been asked endlessly, but going through all the answers i STILL can't get my checkbox/button function to work at all. I finally got it to stop returning "is not a function" but now it's just plain not working.

The purpose is to prevent form submission unless the legal disclaimer box is checked. Standard stuffs, no results... Please help!

```js
function chkThis() {
  var isChk = document.getElementsByName('agecert');
  var isSub = document.getElementById('submit');
  if (isChk.checked == true) {
    isSub.setAttribute("disabled", "false");
  } else {
    isSub.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="agecert" type="checkbox" onclick="chkThis();" style="float: left;height: 20px;width: 25px;border: 1px solid red;" tabindex="8">
  <p style="font-size: 10pt;left: 30px;position: absolute;text-align: justify;">Legal disclaimer stuffs...</p>
  </div>

  <div name="subres" style="width: 400px;height: 50px;top: 235px;left: 30px;position: relative;border: none;">
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" style="left: 65px;" tabindex="9" disabled="disabled">Review Order</button>
    <button name="reset" type="reset" style="left: 245px;" tabindex="10">Reset Form</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Jeremy J Starcher's answer is correct and you should try to understand that thoroughly as it is absolutely essential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all getElementsByName returns a nodeList, you can't access .checked directly, and you dont need == when checking boolean, also i edited disable property to disable/enable the button.
The follow code should work.

```js
function chkThis() {
  var isChk = document.getElementsByName('agecert');
  var isSub = document.getElementById('submit');
  if (isChk[0].checked) {
    isSub.disabled = false;
  } else {
    isSub.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="agecert" type="checkbox" onclick="chkThis();" style="float: left;height: 20px;width: 25px;border: 1px solid red;" tabindex="8">
  <p style="font-size: 10pt;left: 30px;position: absolute;text-align: justify;">Legal disclaimer stuffs...</p>
  </div>

  <div name="subres" style="width: 400px;height: 50px;top: 235px;left: 30px;position: relative;border: none;">
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" style="left: 65px;" tabindex="9" disabled="disabled">Review Order</button>
    <button name="reset" type="reset" style="left: 245px;" tabindex="10">Reset Form</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Daellus You can also remove the if/else statement and can simply write `isSub.disabled = !isChk[0].checked`.

Comment: Thank you Chris! I didn't know it was basically an array. Over the years ive been learning all this piecemeal as I need it. I had tried every combination of ById and ByName. I knew i didn't have to write the rest out in long form but I was hoping to find the problem by writing out everything as detailed as possible. Thank you!

Comment: nodeList is not exactly the same as array, its an array like object, it doesnt have functions like .map arrays have. but you can use methods like Array.prototype.map.call(nodeList, ...) to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

`attributes` and `properties` are different things, but they are somewhat related.

The `attributes` come from the HTML and `properties` are set on the DOM.

In *some* cases changing the attribute will also change the underlying property, and it seems that `disabled` is one of them.  In my experience, this doesn't work for all properties though I can't immediately think of a counterexample.

I've provided code that demonstrates setting the attribute and removing it.  I've also cleaned up a couple of other issues in the code.

In reality, though, Chris Li's answer is better as that sets the `properties` and is a far cleaner approach.

```js
function chkThis() {
  // Note that we are getting the [0] -- the first matching name from the NodeList.
  var isChk = document.getElementsByName('agecert')[0];
  var isSub = document.getElementById('submit');
  if (isChk.checked) {
    isSub.removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    isSub.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="agecert" type="checkbox" onclick="chkThis();" style="float: left;height: 20px;width: 25px;border: 1px solid red;" tabindex="8">
  <p style="font-size: 10pt;left: 30px;position: absolute;text-align: justify;">Legal disclaimer stuffs...</p>
  </div>

  <div name="subres" style="width: 400px;height: 50px;top: 235px;left: 30px;position: relative;border: none;">
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" style="left: 65px;" tabindex="9" disabled="disabled">Review Order</button>
    <button name="reset" type="reset" style="left: 245px;" tabindex="10">Reset Form</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Chris's answer best did the trick, and as you say, the code is cleaner. I'm neat freak codewise once i get something working. I see what you're talking about and will make a point to learn it more thoroughly.